# Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Functions` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions, cocoapods

I was trying to install `pod 'Firebase/Functions'` but failed with the following error:

`[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Functions":
In Podfile:
Firebase/Functions

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Functions` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.`

Here is my pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to 
  use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

 # Pods for MyApp

 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
 pod 'Firebase/Database'
 pod 'Firebase/Auth'
 pod 'Firebase/Messaging' ,'~> 4.6.0'
 pod 'Firebase/Storage'
 pod 'Firebase/Functions'
 pod 'GoogleMaps'
 pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
 pod 'FirebaseUI/Phone'
 pod 'ImageSlideshow', '~> 1.6'
 pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet'
 pod 'SDWebImage'
 pod 'SDWebImage/WebP'

target 'MyAppTests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
   # Pods for testing
end

 target 'MyAppUITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
 # Pods for testing
end
```

end

I have searched for some resources and let me do 3 steps:

```
pod repo update
pod update
pod install
```

I have done with those 3 steps with still not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the `'~> 4.6.0'`.

`FirebaseFunctions` was introduced after Firebase 4.6.0 and is thus incompatible with the version restriction `pod 'Firebase/Messaging' ,'~> 4.6.0'`.

Answer (score 70):

If this solution didn't work for you (It didn't work for me haha), I found another option - here is the initial error I got:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Firestore":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Firestore (= 6.34.0, ~> 6.0)

  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Firestore

    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 1.0.6, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore (= 7.3.0)

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Firestore, Firebase/Firestore (= 6.34.0, ~> 6.0), Firebase/Firestore (= 7.3.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

My Solution was to switch my ios/Podile's first line to `platform :ios, '10.0'` and run:

```
pod update
pod install
```

Pod Update updates Cocoa Pods, and for me it also installed the packages

Date: 4/21/21

Comment: pod update         worked for me in my Flutter project. Thanks!!!

Comment: pod update worked for me in a React Native project `react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.68.2`

Answer (score 18):

I simply hat to run `pod update` in the ios folder of my flutter project

Answer (score 6):

You need to increase your deployment target. Go to Project Navigator (Cmd + 1), select the your app's target and increase the `iOS Deployment Target` to the minimum required by Firebase (iOS >= 8). Finally, rerun pod install:

```
pod install
```

Comment: My deployment target is version 11.0 why it is still not working?

Comment: I increased it to 11 and it worked for me with Flutter 2.

Comment: @FLUXparticle I ran into this after a fresh install of the firebase_core and bumping it to 
 the deployment target to 11.0 also worked for me 

Comment: @Ridwan I looked into the source of firebase and 10 would actually be enough.

Comment: @VisalSambo `10.0` worked for me with `firebase_core: ^1.13.1` and `firebase_messaging: ^11.2.8`. No need to restrict it to higher version, since you loose potential compatible devices / iOS versions.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the error you need to require a higher minimum deployment target.

Go to your Podfile and uncomment

```
#platform :ios, '9.0'
```

Then change the version to 10

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

Run the build again. Answer was taken from [here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/4709#issuecomment-762296217)

Answer (score 4):

Delete `Podfile.lock` file and
then `pod repo update` then try to install pod

Comment: This works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

change pod 'Firebase/Messaging' ,'~> 4.6.0' to pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

And run pod install

Answer (score 1):

As @Brady mentioned you need to update your podfile #platform line.

Mine also has this post install function at the bottom that needs to be updated as well, and seems to override even the target deployment set in Xcode.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

run

```
pod install
```

and then according to your package name

```
pod update PACKAGE_NAME
```

Example:

```
pod update Firebase/Functions
```